# Can I run DC fan below rated current?

Tags: dc

Can I run a dc fan (rating-24v,105w) calculated current I 4.3I approx. below rated adapter source of 24v 2.5A?

Will this damage my adapter or fan?

while testing I found that my DC fan is creating a hauling sound. Why is this sound?

Comment: What exactly is a "hauling sound"? Hauling is not an activity I generally associate with having a sound.

Comment: The "duplicated" question asks the opposite (supply current higher than load, even if answers answers both cases) and the sound is not addressed at all. It's a useful link, but not a full answer to the question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: For the sound, I suspect it is the current limiting that works by activating/deactivating the current quite fast, making your fan "vibrate" at this frequency.

Answer (score 3):

No. If your DC fan requires a 105 W supply then it will demand 105 / 24 amps from the supply.

If the supply can't supply enough current one of two things will happen:

1. The power supply will go into current limit and the voltage will collapse to limit the current to its rated value.
2. If the power supply doesn't have current limiting then it will try to deliver the current drawn by the fan, will overheat and potentially burn out with the possibility of starting a fire.

Comment: But my fan was running at full speed using 24vdc 2.5A adapter. it was making houling sound

Answer (score 1):

No because the adapter cannot provide the current the fan needs.

Comment: But my fan was running at full speed using 24vdc 2.5A adapter. it was making houling sound